# Ionic app deep links are not working properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, deep-linking

In this code when I click on button it always open https://apps.apple.com URL instead of opening the App Store. I want to achieve that if the app isn't installed in device then it should only go to the App Store, otherwise it should open this URL: https://apps.apple.com .

```
popover.onDidDismiss()
    .then(async (decision) => {
        if (exiStatus.status === 'registered' && decision.data) {
            const options: AppLauncherOptions = {}
            if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                options.uri = 'exiapp://referral'
            } else {
                options.packageName = 'com.iprescribeexercise.app.android.iPrescribe'
            }
            this.appLauncher.canLaunch(options)
                .then((canLaunch: boolean) => {
                    this.appLauncher.launch(options);
                })
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                        window.open('https://apps.apple.com')
                    } else {
                        window.open('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iprescribeexercise.app.android.iPrescribe')
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
       console.log(data,"chintan");
      this.zone.run(() => {
        // Example url: https://beerswift.app/tabs/tab2
        // slug = /tabs/tab2
        const slug = data.url.split("apps.").pop();
        
        if (slug == "apple.com") {
         // DO SOMTHING
        }
        else {
         
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
        }
        // If no match, do nothing - let regular routing
        // logic take over
      });
    });
```

add this code in your in **intializeApp()** method into **appcomponent.ts** and also add some line in **manifaist file** if you running for android.

**https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links  follow this link you get all your answer.**